# Where are the controller components?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to move to compile-time dependency injection using Play Framework 2.6 in Java. My reading of the Play 2.6 Migration Guide under "[Scala Controller Changes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#scala-controller-changes)", leads me to believe that I should pass an instance of `ControllerComponents` into my controller classes; but I can't find a method that provides those components.

`play.api.BuiltInComponentsFromContext` defines a `controllerComponents()` method, but the Java version of that class, `play.BuiltInComponentsFromContext`, does not.

What is going on?

Under "[Using Dependency Injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaActionsComposition#using-dependency-injection)" in the Play 2.6 (Java) documentation, it talks about overriding `javaHandlerComponents` in `BuiltInComponents`. OK fine, but does that mean I have to define all of my actions as separate classes? Can I not use Controller classes if I want to do compile-time dependency injection in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section in Play 2.6 Migration Guide entitled "Scala Controller Changes" is properly named: it applies only to controllers written in Scala. Use the same action composition approach that you've used pre-2.6.